# Building a DOM Document with tagsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom

I cannot make TagSoup work. I'm using the code that follows, but when I print the Node returned by the parser (the line with System.err.println(doc);) , I always get "[#document: null]".

I don't know how to find the bug in this code or, whichever it is, the origin of the problem. Please help!

```
public final Document parseDOM(final File fileToParse) {
  Parser p = new Parser();
  SAX2DOM sax2dom = null;
  org.w3c.dom.Node doc  = null;

  try { 

        URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        p.setFeature(Parser.namespacesFeature, false);
        p.setFeature(Parser.namespacePrefixesFeature, false);
        sax2dom = new SAX2DOM();
        p.setContentHandler(sax2dom);
        p.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())));
        doc = sax2dom.getDOM();
        System.err.println(doc);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO handle exception
     e.printStackTrace();
  }


  return doc.getOwnerDocument();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation on `getOwnerDocument`:

> When this node is a Document or a DocumentType which is not used with any Document yet, this is null.

Since `getDOM` in your case should return a `Document`, you could simply cast the return value or change the type of `doc` to `Document`.

Comment: I read that doc but I didn't realize that Document is a subinterface of Node - now I have the big picture, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your parser is working, but you just can't print out a node like that. The easiest way to print out a node and all its children is to use an XML Serializer like this:

```
          Writer out = new StringWriter();
          XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(out, new OutputFormat());
          serializer.serialize(doc);
          System.out.println(out.toString());
```

Comment: you're right, I didn't know that Node.tostring prints the parent document.
Anyway, I have now the problem of getting a Document instead of a Node... as doc.getOwnerDocument() returns null (I thought that was the right way to obatain a Document)

Comment: just cast it like this: `return (Document)doc`